# Symfony Entity form type across OneToMany relationship

Tags: forms, doctrine, symfony

I have a entity Event which is related to another entity Parameter by a third entity EventsParameters.

Parameter contain all possible parameters for each Event. Let say "isSomething" and "isSomethingElse"

In my event create form I want to set "isSomething" and "isSomethingElse" to true or false

So I have tried to add an entity field in my form:

```
 ->add('parameters', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'    => 'AppBundle:Parameter' ,
                'multiple' => true , ))
```

But I'm not sure about which class I have to set. Parameter or EventsParameters? I can't get started!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just had this line in my form builder

```
->add('enventsParameters' ,EntityType::class , array(
                'class'    => 'AppBundle:Parameter' ,
                'choice_label' => function ($obj) {
                    return   $obj->getParameterName();
                },
                'expanded' => true ,
                'multiple' => true , ))
```